# Group by category and distinct dates in one column

Tags: r

The data is as follows:

```
a <- c('2020-01-01','2020-01-03','2020-01-05','2020-05-01','2020-06-01')
b <- c('X1','X1','X1','X2','X2')
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Group by column 'b' and mutate a new_col with all distinct values of col'a'.

Sample output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all the unique dates in one cell using `toString` and add count of distinct dates using `n_distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  summarise(distinct_dates = toString(unique(a)), 
            distinct_count = n_distinct(a)) -> result
result

#   b     distinct_dates                     distinct_count
#  <chr> <chr>                                       <int>
#1 X1    2020-01-01, 2020-01-03, 2020-01-05              3
#2 X2    2020-05-01, 2020-06-01                          2
```

In `data.table` you can do :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(distinct_dates = toString(unique(a)), 
              distinct_count = uniqueN(a)), b]
```